# Why can't I get a output lower than 0V in this circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

In the image above green is my input (node left side capacitor) and blue is my output (node right side of the capacitor).
I would expect that the blue sinusoidal looking signal would follow the input, but it does not do this. Why is this the case? Can you explain this with open circuit and short circuit equivalents for the diode?

Comment: Voltages are always *between* two points.  Saying the green signal is at the left side of the cap without a reference is non-sensical.  I'll assume you mean the bottom node to be the implied 0V reference.  Also, you should be able to see for yourself that the text from the diode and the voltage source are obscuring each other.  Science requires attention to detail.  -1 for the sloppiness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you expect the two signals to be the same since you have a diode in there.  If you short across the diode, you will get what you seem to be expecting.  With the diode in there, it will obviously be doing something else.

While the diode changing things should be expected, the plots you are showing don't make sense either.  The voltage on the left side of the cap (all voltage implicitly with respect to the - side of the voltage source) will always be the voltage source output by definition of what a voltage source does.  With the capacitor initially discharged (0 V across it), the diode is reverse biased and thefore act like a open circuit.  The voltage on both sides of the cap will be the same, as your plot shows.

When the input voltage goes negative, the diode will conduct and the cap will get charge up to a negative value.  After the first complete negative half-cycle, the cap will be charged up to the negative peak and that voltage will remain across it forever (assuming ideal components).  After that, the voltage on the right side of the cap should follow the voltage on the left side, plus the peak negative voltage.

There is a discrepancy somewhere, since your plots don't seem to be showing what they should.  It is impossible to tell what since there are already other obvious points of lack of attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I get a output lower than 0V in this circuit?

For simplicity, assume the diode is ideal.

If the output voltage (with respect to the 'ground' node) is the cathode of the diode, the output voltage cannot be less than the anode voltage.

But the anode voltage is zero volts thus, the output voltage cannot be less than zero volts.

For a real diode, the output voltage can be negative the forward voltage drop of the diode, e.g., -0.7V.

> Can you explain this with open circuit and short circuit equivalents
>   for the diode?

Since the diode allows only a counter-clockwise (CCW) current, the capacitor cannot discharge with a clockwise (CW) current.  Thus, after some initial CCW charging current, the capacitor develops a fixed voltage across equal to the amplitude of the AC source.

This voltage is *added* to the source voltage.  For example, if the source voltage is given by

$$v_S(t) = A\cos\omega t$$

the capacitor eventually charges to $A$ volts which, when added to the source voltage, gives and output voltage of

$$v_O(t) = A\cos\omega t + A = A (\cos\omega t + 1)$$

which appears to be consistent with the blue trace.